# Interpolate in variable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interpolation

I'm trying to make my page dynamic, based on params passed by the url. I want to use the params to change variables like this

```
<h3><%= "$subproject_title_#{params[:num]}_1" %></h3>
```

Obviously, this just prints the string, but if I remove the quotation marks, half the line just gets commented out.
What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: `public_send("$subproject_title_#{params[:num]}_1")`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko That gives me an undefined method error.

Comment: can you use `instance variables` instead of global?

Comment: You can decide it in your controller, You cannot access params directly in view.

Comment: @GaneshSagare Yes you can. It does print the correct param value

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon The variables are stored in a model and have to be accesible in all views

Comment: you can move it to a helper instead

Comment: @JustusP try with eval("$subproject_title_#{params[:num]}_1")

Comment: @GaneshSagare Thanks! That worked :)

Comment: @JustusP You really should have a look at the answer of Stefan. The eval solution is completely insecure. And please if you found your answer, mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some rules of thumb:

- Don't use global variables
- Don't build variables dynamically
- Don't use `eval`

Furthermore, try to avoid accessing `params` in your view, that should be handled in the controller.

Instead of global variables, you can use instance variables. They are shared between your controller and your view.

Instead of dynamically generated variables, you can use a hash:

```
@titles = {
  '1' = 'title one',
  '2' = 'title two',
  '3' = 'title three',
}
```

Then, instead of `eval`, you can use [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) to fetch a value for a given `num`.

You can assign that value to an instance variable in your controller:

```
def index
  @title = @titles.fetch(params[:num], 'default title')
end
```

That instance variable can be accessed in you view:

```
<h3><%= @title %></h3>
```

---

You could also create a `Page` model with a `title` and a (unique) `num` attribute to store your page details. The change to your controller would be quite simple:

```
def index
  @page = Page.find_by(num: params[:num])
end
```

And in your view:

```
<h3><%= @page.title %></h3>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
eval("$subproject_title_#{params[:num]}_1")
```

Comment: `eval` is a very powerful tool. You should avoid it unless you really know what you are doing. That particular code is vulnerable to code injection. For example, setting `:num` to ``";_1=`ls`;"`` would make your view print a directory listing.